# Hide last two items in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code , in which I want to hide last two items in a div :

```js
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
  $('.showRooms').slice(-2).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showRooms">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

But its not working, The last two `div`s are not removing.

What am I missing ?

Comment: $('.showRooms > div').slice(-2).remove();

Comment: I've updated my response. you can look at my another methods :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hide the children of your selected div:

```js
var children = $('.showRooms').children();

$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
  // hide last 2
  children.show().slice(-2).hide();

  // or use remove if you want them removing instead of hiding:
  // children.slice(-2).remove();
});

$('.toggleRoom-1').click(function() {
  // hide all but last 2
  children.show().slice(0, -2).hide();

  // or use remove if you want them removing instead of hiding:
  // children.slice(0, -2).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showRooms">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>

<div class="toggleRoom">click to hide last 2</div>

<div class="toggleRoom-1">click to hide all but last 2</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And how can we remove all except last two divs ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `$('.showRooms').find('div').slice(-2).remove()` as there are three `div`s inside the `div` with class `showRooms` so you need to select the last two `div` using `slice(-2)`.

```js
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
  $('.showRooms').find('div').slice(-2).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showRooms">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<button class='toggleRoom'>Click</button>
```

Based on your comment to remove all `div` except last two `div`s you need to do:

```js
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
  var elem = $('.showRooms').find('div');
  elem.slice(0, elem.length-2).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showRooms">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<button class='toggleRoom'>Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And how can we remove all except last two divs ?

Comment: @Gammer in that case you need to select all the elements from `0` to array `length -2`. I have updated the answer. Have a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

If your html is exactly like your above code, you can try this:

```
$(".showRooms div:not(:first-child)");
```

else try one of this functions! Simple and short:

```
function GetExpectFirstDivs(c/*count 4 ignore from first*/){
    return $(".showRooms>div:nth-child(n+"+(c+1)+")");
}
function GetExpectLastDivs(c){
    return $(".showRooms>div:nth-last-child(n+"+(c+1)+")");
}
function GetFirstDivs(c/*count*/){
    return !c?$():$(".showRooms>div:not(:gt("+(c-1)+"))");
}
function GetLastDivs(c){
    return !c?$():$(".showRooms>div:gt(-"+(c+1)+")");
}
```

Now, for example: **how can we remove all except last two (n) divs?**:

```
GetExpectLastDivs(2/*n*/).remove();
```

Comment: Will not work if there are four or five div. OP just want to remove the last two divs

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And how can we remove all except last two divs ?

Comment: you can test second method in my updated answer (@Ankit Agarwal).

Comment: Your welcome @Grammer. you can do it like this: `$(".showRooms div:lt(2)").remove();`

Answer (score 1):

you have to use selector on its children not on the div it selef

like `.showRooms > div` (direct div children) or `.showRooms  div` (all div children)

```js
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
    $('.showRooms > div').slice(-2).toggle();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggleRoom">toggle rooms</button>

<div class="showRooms">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

To hide other exept the two use .not()

see below snippet

```js
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
    var $lastTwo = $('.showRooms > div').slice(-2);
    $('.showRooms > div').not($lastTwo).toggle();
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="toggleRoom">toggle rooms</button>

<div class="showRooms">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And how can we remove all except last two divs ?

Comment: @Gammer by using not() or slice(0,-2)

Answer (score 0):

For same HTML code, you need to change in Js
The only issue is you have forgotten to add child element type

```
 $('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
        $('.showRooms > div').slice(-2).remove();
    });
```

another method is

```
$(".showRooms div:not (:first-child)");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are missing:

```
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
    $('.showRooms').children().slice(-2).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change below JS

```
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
   $('.showRooms div').slice(-2).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `div` selector,add it.

```
  $('.showRooms div').slice(-2).remove();
```

If you want to be more specific you can use direct child selector.

```
  $('.showRooms > div').slice(-2).remove();
```

one more selector :

```
$('.showRooms div:last-child').prev('div').andSelf().remove();
```

```js
$('.toggleRoom').click(function() {
  $('.showRooms div').slice(-2).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showRooms">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

If you wish to remove all except last two you can do this.

```
 $('.showRooms div').slice(-2).addClass('preserve');
$('.showRooms div:not(.preserve)').remove();
$('.showRooms div).removeClass('preserve');
```

This is once way you can do it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And how can we remove all except last two divs ?

Comment: added the code to remove all except last two , check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is hide the last two item - you can do it with just css

```css
.showRooms div:nth-last-of-type(1),
.showRooms div:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="showRooms">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

if you want to show only the last two - then flip the css around to hide all divs then show only the last two:

```css
.showRooms div {display: none;
}

.showRooms div:nth-last-of-type(1),
.showRooms div:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="showRooms">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, And how can we remove all except last two divs ?

Comment: I am sorry - I though you wanted to hide the last two - I have edited y answer to show the flipped scenario - hide all divs and then show the last two.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [:gt() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('.showRooms > div:gt(-3)').hide(); // hide last 2 items
```

```js
$('.toggleRoom').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.showRooms > div:gt(-3)').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="toggleRoom">click to hide last 2</button>

<div class="showRooms">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```